# Keyboard automático em Input com Ionic

Tags: ionic3

Preciso de uma rotina em Ionic que chama o Keyboard do celular para um ion-input ao entrar na página.

Um exemplo de página seria:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <form>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-input #user name="user" type="text" placeholder="Usuário"></ion-input>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

O que eu quero é utilizando os Navigating Lifecycle do Ionic (acredito eu que nesse caso usando o ionViewDidEnter) trazer o foco e o Keyboard no campo automaticamente, já tentei alguns códigos mas infelizmente as vezes funciona e outras vezes não, obrigado desde já.

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta. o que vc quer dizer com trazer o foco?

Answer (score 0):

Com a classe Keyboard você pode checar se existe já alguma entrada com foco, caso não você pode focá-la e utilizando o plugin você pode forçar a exibição do teclado.

Classe Keyboard:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Keyboard/

Plugin:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/